# How can I read the value of a Realm variable in an iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have just started coding. I am making an iOS app with Swift that needs to be able to store two variables even when the app is exited. For this, I am using Realm. I am able to write those two variables, but when I try to read them, I cannot build my project.

I have tried many tutorats, but failed each time I tried to apply them to my problem.

Here is my Realm class:

```
class Info: Object {
    dynamic var name  = ""
    dynamic var gender  = ""
}
```

How can I read the value of these two variables in my ViewController?

When I try to read the variable, I have an error on the line

```
guard let info = realm.objects(Info.self).first else {return}
```

of my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    guard let info = realm.objects(Info.self).first else {return}
    let name = info.name
    let gender = info.gender

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: " I cannot build my project." Why not? And what are those < and > doing there? ( I never seen this ?! )

Comment: I have this wild guess that you are trying to use some arcane characters instead of `""`.

Comment: Sorry about the «  », my computer’s autocorrect did that. I correctes my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access `Realm` variables like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
guard let info = realm.objects(Info.self).first else {return}
let name = info.name
let gender = info.gender
```

However, if you don't plan on storing more complex data on storage, I would suggest you just use `UserDefaults`, for such a simple task it is easier to use.

You should also change the `«  »` to proper `"` signs if you want to store String literals.

For the edited part of your question:
`guard let info = realm.objects(Info.self).first else {return}` has to happen inside your `viewDidLoad` function. You cannot access `realm`, which is an instance property of your class, before your class is actually initialised, hence the error you get. If you need info to be an instance property, initialise it as an optional and access it inside `viewDidLoad`.

First option - if you only need access to `info` inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let realm = try! Realm()
        guard let info = realm.objects(Info.self).first else {return}
        let name = info.name
        let gender = info.gender
    }

}
```

Second option - if you need to access `info` everywhere in your class instance:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var info: Info?    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        info = realm.objects(Info.self).first else {return}
        let name = info.name
        let gender = info.gender
    }

}
```

If this is your initial view controller, declaring realm as an instance property might prove to be problematic, since your class might be instantiated before your `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` function finished execution and hence your `realm schema` won't be set up properly by the time you try to access it in `SettingsViewController`. If this is the case, just move the line `let realm = try! Realm()` inside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: When I tried building my project, it failed with the error message: « Cannot use instance member ‘realm’ within property initialiser; property initialiser run before ‘self’ is available ». What should I do?

Comment: Please include the code which actually caused the error.

Comment: I added the line in my question.

Comment: No worries. If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var personInfo : PresonInfo?
    let realm = try! Realm()    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let user = try! realm.objects(PresonInfo.self)
        for person in user {
        let name = personInfo?.username
       }
    }
}
```